# Font Awesome Icons not displaying

Tags: css, font-awesome

There are lots of threads about this, I know. I spend the last 2 days trying all the solutions in the other questions but still can't fix it.

As you can see here: http://www.hoyhombre.com/00002020/6-tips-que-todo-hombre-debe-saber-sobre-usar-perfumes/ font awesome icons aren't showing up. They should show up on the left and bottom on the facebook and twitter social share button.

Comment: we need to see your code here with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the `-ism` at the end? For instance, on the Facebook icon, the class should just be `fa fa-ism fa-facebook` and it'll work just fine.

Comment: I think I love you, haha. I spent two days trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot!